# python Threading and locks for a global variable not behaving as expected?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the code below:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

i = 1
lock = Lock()
def t_func():
    global i
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        local_i = i
        i += 1
        lock.release()
        sleep(1)
        print(i)
```

expected behavior is to get unique i values inside each thread always but running 30 simultaneous threads can cause output as below:

```
743743
744
745

747
748
749
750
751
752
753
754754
755

757
758
```

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Did you mean to print `local_i` instead of `i`?

Comment: You are printing `i` outside of the lock, so it may be changed in another thread.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner your comment should be an Answer. It almost certainly is _the_ answer. Voting to close as "...caused by a typo" since OP clearly intended to `print(local_i)`.

Comment: Also note: If you change the code to `print(local_i)`, then you can expect the program to print every number and, to print each number only one time, but you still cannot expect it to print the numbers in ascending order because the `print` call is outside of the critical section. Plus, judging from the output you showed, you still will sometimes see blank lines and two numbers printed on the same line.